# using screen session in shebang of a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I have recently come across this [post](http://www.kormoc.com/2013/06/19/force-a-bash-script-to-run-in-screen/) which says that it is possible to force a script to run in screen with a shebang. My question is, how does one do this if I want to reconnect to an existing screen session (and thus force the script to run under screen).

So, on my server, when I do `screen -list`, I see:

```
There is a screen on:
    22566.myscreen  (10/26/13 23:47:09) (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-admin.
```

Now, I have the following bash script, and I would like the bash script to be run with the above screen session. At the moment, I have something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/screen -r "myscreen" /bin/bash
# /home/foo/jobscripts/script.sh
#

echo $STY
git status
touch /home/foo/jobscripts/testsuccess.txt
exit 0
```

... but this obviously does not work and tells me `Error: Unknown option r "myscreen" /bin/bash` Wondering if there was a way to specify in shebang to reattach to my above screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Linux, I think we should just use something like `pid.sessionname`.

For other Unix-like OS, it may also indicate the TTY like this `pid.tty.sessionname`.

To be sure, consult your manpage of screen : `man screen`

Comment: I have tried `pid.sessionname`. Idoes not work.. It complains `Must be connected to a terminal.` :(